# When I am create a new empty activity the layout R.layout.layoutname is not resolved?

Tags: android, android-activity

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.allelectricalformula.R;
import com.example.allelectricalformula.Tools.AppConstants;

public class ImageViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_view);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Position is"+ AppConstants.postion2 , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61906398/12478830

Comment: It seems to be a IDE bug ... are you sure you are on latest version of android studio ? If you restart your project i.e close it and open agian it will be no more..

Comment: just rebuild project

Answer (score 1):

Things you could do:

1. Build -> Rebuild project
2. Build -> Clean project
3. File -> Invalidate caches / restart